# Execution failed for task ':iris_method_channel:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, cmake

My environment :

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS  64-bit

Flutter 3.10.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f468f3366c
Engine • revision cdbeda788a
Tools • Dart 3.0.6 • DevTools 2.23.1

**Error message :**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':iris_method_channel:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1429] error when building with cmake using /home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/src/CMakeLists.txt: -- android-16 is not supported for arm64-v8a. Using minimum supported LP64 version 21.
  -- Android: Targeting API '21' with architecture 'arm64', ABI 'arm64-v8a', and processor 'aarch64'
  -- Android: Selected unified Clang toolchain
  -- The C compiler identification is Clang 12.0.8
  -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 12.0.8
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
  -- Check for working C compiler: /home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
  -- Check for working C compiler: /home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang - broken
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "/home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
      /usr/bin/cmake \
        -H/home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/src \
        -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android \
        -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON \
        -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=16 \
        -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16 \
        -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a \
        -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a \
        -DANDROID_NDK=/home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620 \
        -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620 \
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
        -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/ninja \
        "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/mnt/secpart/old data/Desktop/work/zidoFlutter/build/iris_method_channel/intermediates/cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/obj/arm64-v8a" \
        "-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/mnt/secpart/old data/Desktop/work/zidoFlutter/build/iris_method_channel/intermediates/cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/obj/arm64-v8a" \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
        -B/home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/arm64-v8a \
        -GNinja
    from /home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/android
  CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
    The C compiler
      "/home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang"
    is not able to compile a simple test program.
    It fails with the following output:
      Change Dir: /home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
      Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_92f1c && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_92f1c.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
      [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_92f1c
      FAILED: cmTC_92f1c 
      : && /home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot=/home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fexceptions  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-undefined  -Wl,--gc-sections -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -llz4 -lgpg-error -luuid -lpthread -ldl -lepoxy -lfontconfig CMakeFiles/cmTC_92f1c.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_92f1c  -latomic -lm && :
      ld: error: --fix-cortex-a53-843419 is only supported on AArch64 targets
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:10 (project)
* Try:
> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':iris_method_channel:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:293)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:417)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:339)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: [CXX1429] error when building with cmake using /home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/src/CMakeLists.txt: -- android-16 is not supported for arm64-v8a. Using minimum supported LP64 version 21.
-- Android: Targeting API '21' with architecture 'arm64', ABI 'arm64-v8a', and processor 'aarch64'
-- Android: Selected unified Clang toolchain
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 12.0.8
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 12.0.8
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang - broken
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
    /usr/bin/cmake \
      -H/home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/src \
      -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android \
      -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON \
      -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=16 \
      -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16 \
      -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a \
      -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a \
      -DANDROID_NDK=/home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620 \
      -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620 \
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
      -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/ninja \
      "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/mnt/secpart/old data/Desktop/work/zidoFlutter/build/iris_method_channel/intermediates/cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/obj/arm64-v8a" \
      "-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/mnt/secpart/old data/Desktop/work/zidoFlutter/build/iris_method_channel/intermediates/cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/obj/arm64-v8a" \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
      -B/home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/arm64-v8a \
      -GNinja
  from /home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/android
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler
    "/home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.
  It fails with the following output:
    Change Dir: /home/sloppy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/iris_method_channel-1.1.0/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/h3c505l3/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_92f1c && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_92f1c.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_92f1c
    FAILED: cmTC_92f1c 
    : && /home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot=/home/sloppy/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fexceptions  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-undefined  -Wl,--gc-sections -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -llz4 -lgpg-error -luuid -lpthread -ldl -lepoxy -lfontconfig CMakeFiles/cmTC_92f1c.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_92f1c  -latomic -lm && :
    ld: error: --fix-cortex-a53-843419 is only supported on AArch64 targets
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (project)
    at com.android.builder.errors.IssueReporter.reportError(IssueReporter.kt:112)
    at com.android.builder.errors.IssueReporter.reportError$default(IssueReporter.kt:108)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment.log(IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment.kt:114)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.ThreadLoggingEnvironment$Companion.reportFormattedErrorToCurrentLogger(LoggingEnvironment.kt:227)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.LoggingEnvironmentKt.errorln(LoggingEnvironment.kt:60)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.configure(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.kt:111)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildJsonTask.doTaskAction(ExternalNativeBuildJsonTask.kt:72)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.UnsafeOutputsTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:65)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.UnsafeOutputsTask.taskAction(UnsafeOutputsTask.kt:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:236)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:204)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:181)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:254)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:281)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:293)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:417)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:339)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 3m 36s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:456:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:208:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:116:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1336:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:296:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:244:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:91:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

Flutter doctor command output :

```
• No issues found!
```

I've tried :

flutter clean command
removing .pub-cache folder
re-installing flutter
installing the latest android studio version
updating flutter linux dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev liblzma-dev
```

but it keeps giving me the same error

NOTE : flutter build command is working with my colleagues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem by uninstalling flutter sdk that I've installed using snap and then manually installing it